# Trouble with after update trigger for Quote Line Item

Tags: apex

I am working on a trigger on a custom object that when a field IncludeWithOrder__c is marked as true a after update trigger is fired to add that product to the Quote as a QuoteLineItem, but I am currently **getting saying that the Product2 field doesn't exist on the QuoteLineItem object**, I have tried Product2Id and Product2 but neither seem to work, any help would be awesome. here is the trigger that I have currently:

```
 trigger WearableTrigger on Wearable__c (after update) {

    List<QuoteLineItem> item = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
        for (Wearable__c wear: Trigger.New)
            if (wear.IncludeWithOrder__c == TRUE){
                item.add(new QuoteLineItem(
                    //ProductId = wear.Product__r.Id,
                    QuoteId = wear.Quote__r.Id,
                    UnitPrice = wear.Price__c,
                    Quantity = wear.Quantity__c));
            }
        insert item;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the Id's for Product and Quote, you actually don't need to use the `__r.Id` versions  Just replace `__r.Id` with `__c` and it will work...

Furthermore, if you want any non-ID relationship fields, those are not included in the Trigger.new context...  You'll need to do as follows:

```
for (Wearable__c wear: [SELECT Id, Product__c, Quote__c, Price__c, Quantity__c, IncludeWithOrder__c, Product__r.SomeField__c FROM Wearable__c WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New])
```

Sounds like you also need the pricebookentryid, so create a map before your "for" loop:

```
Map<Id, Id> mapProductToPBE = new Map<Id, Id>();
for (Product2 p : [SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id = :someId]) {
    mapProductToPBE.put(p.Product2Id, p.Id);
}
```

... then reference that in your loop by replacing `//ProductId = wear.Product__r.Id` with `PricebookEntryId = mapProductToPBE.get(wear.Product__c)`

Comment: After doing what you had suggested, I still get the compile error of "Invalid field Product2 for SObject QuoteLineItem (Line 7), while that is the API name of the field on the QuoteLineItem object.

Comment: What is the lookup object for Wearable__c.Product__c?  It sounds like they are incompatible...

Comment: It is a look up to the Product standard object, same object that the QuoteLineItem look ups to.

Comment: I suggest creating a map that maps product id to pricebookentry id that you want...

Comment: Ah that is a good point/idea, I will put that to use! thank you!

Comment: Updated my entry to reflect...